# Bootstrap - submenu as a untouchable and stable belt

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When i click in other place from site, dropdown disappear. It should be still visible, and it should change yourself when i click on other tab from menu

[image: Effect]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? And if so, could you share your findings with us so we can help you with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change CSS:

```
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav > li.dropdown.open {
  position: static;
}
.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
    display:table; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.dropdown-menu>li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Is that affects what you wanted?

Note, that you have to apply this rules after bootstrap.css have been loaded in your page.

Comment: Good but still not this what i want. Check screen under this comment :P